# Disable reading and writing for a database column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-migration

I want to remove a column in a large table, but first I want to disable reading from and writing to that column. If either of these is attempted, an exception should be raised.

One way of doing this would be to override all the methods that can read from or write to that column. For example, if the table `users` had a column `name` I could write

```
def name
  raise "posts.name column is disabled"
end

def name=
  raise "posts.name column is disabled"
end

def read_attribute(column)
  raise "posts.name column is disabled" if column.to_sym == :name
  super
end

def write_attribute(column)
  raise "posts.name column is disabled" if column.to_sym == :name
end

# Others???
```

But this is verbose, and I doubt whether it's even an exhaustive list of methods that can access that column. Is there a better way? I'm using Rails 4.2.

Comment: out of curiosity - why would you need it? :)

Comment: Ya, why would you need that? you should also update the consumers (the places where these methods are used) as a part of your refactoring too. So once you did that, you won't need to implement this.